# Search and replace in a lot of files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm trying to search and replace a string in a lot of files, this is what I'm currently doing :
`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F`
then type my string and finally : `replace`.
The problem is that Sublime Text **OPEN** every file, replace my string and I have to save them all then close them.

I need Sublime to only replace the string, is there a settings or something ?

Comment: use notepad++ for search and replace in files

Comment: It's not about `"how can I replace in all my files, I can't do it"`, it's `"is there a way to do it more efficiently"`.

Comment: and Notepad++ does it the way we want it. No save is required.

Comment: You could just open a new window (`File` -> `New Window`), do the find and replace and then `File` -> `Save All`, close the window and go on where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible in Sublime Text, you could use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) just for this feature or do the following:

> You could just open a new window (`File` -> `New Window`), do the find and replace and then `File` -> `Save All`, close the window and go on where you left off.